# Making a div 100% of it's container, when the div sets the height of it's parent

Tags: css, html, height

Here is my HTML structure:

```
<li>
     <div class='wrapper'>
          <div class='controller'> ... </div>
          <div class='preview'> ... </div>
     </div>
</li>
```

The content in the 'controller' and 'preview' divs can vary, and thus so can the height of the content.  There isn't necessary a correlation between the heights of the 'controller' and 'preview' divs.  In a given wrapper one might be 10px high while the other one is 100px high.  I want the smaller one to expand to match the height of the smaller one.  Using a css rule of "height: 100%;" doesn't work because there's no explicit height set to the wrapper, and again i can't set a height to the wrapper, because the content inside of it can vary.

I am looking for a solution in css not javascript.  My company has a strict policy of writing for browsers that don't have javascript enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 100% height for a div will only take up as much as the content of the div needs. You will have
to explicitly set the height.

You can do this by using some javascript:

```
var height = document.getElementById('parentDiv').style.height;
document.getElementById('childDiv').style.height = height +'px';
```

Comment: I really didn't want a javascript solution but this looks like it's the only thing i can do. :-(

Comment: Yea, I understand but there's just some disconnect on css with block heights unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

It could be set with a script or when you don't want to use JS you could use the faux columns technique:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two divs are next to eachother (using a float or whatever), this is a very common problem in HTML that still doesn't have a native solution.

One method to solve this is the faux columns, but this has it's limitations: usually a very wide border is used to fake the background color of the smaller div, so you can only use a solid color.

If you really need the height to be the same (for reasons of using the same borders on both divs, background images, or even positioned elements inside the divs that both need to be in the bottom of the div) you'll have to use a javascript solution.